# High Level Process, Calculating Cepstrum When You Only Have Spectrum

Tags: fft, matlab, cepstral-analysis

I am not a DSP expert, so I would like someone to check my thought process:

I have a text file representing the spectrum (calculated by some FFT hardware), and I'd like to calculate a cepstrum.  I'm using Octave in the examples below, but it's not required.

- My source data is two columns: `frequency`, `amplitude`, i.e.:

> ```
> +----------+----------+
> | 0.00E+00 | 6.93E+01 |
> | 1.00E+01 | 6.95E+01 |
> | 2.00E+01 | 7.38E+01 |
> | ...      | ...      |
> | 2.00E+03 | 6.51E+01 |
> +----------+----------
> ```

- Load the data in to Octave, and use `ifft` to put the spectrum into
  the time domain.  Then use `rceps` to calculate the cepstrum:

  `rceps(ifft(my_data(:,2))); % my_data is the 2000x2 matrix from above`
- Plot the result of `rceps`.  The resulting curve should equal cepstrum that would have been produced if I had started with a time domain signal.

---

Is this a correct way to find the cepstrum when only spectrum (FFT) is available, or, is there a flaw in my thought process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cepstrum is defined as:

$C = | \mathcal{F} \log( P(f) ) |^2$

$\mathcal{F}$ is a Fourier transform and $P(f)$ is the power spectrum.  If you've got the power spectrum for the signal there is no need to go back to the time domain.  Just take the logarithm, compute an FFT, take the magnitude squared of the result.

Also, the data you list is strictly positive and real so I'm assuming it's the spectrum.  At the end of your question you put spectrum (FFT).  If what you had was an FFT of a real-valued time domain signal, and not a spectrum, I would expect it to have an imaginary part.

Comment: I believe it is $| \mathcal{F} log(|S(f)|^{2})|^{2}$

Comment: If $S(f)$ is a spectrum and not just an FFT then it has already been squared.

Comment: Yeah, but $S(f)$ is usually taken to just mean the DFT, so it may get confusing if someone arbitrarily changes the meaning.

Comment: Yes, I only have the real part.

Comment: When you say "take the magnitude squared", that means do something like: `abs(fft_result).**2`?  Because `fft_result` has complex numbers `abs(number).**2 !=  number.**2`, as it would with real numbers.

Comment: You're right.  When I said take the magnitude squared I meant do abs(fft_result).**2

Comment: @Mohammad If you interpret the spectrum as an energy density and assign it the symbol $S(f)$ it should make sense that it is squared, because it is energy.  I believe calling a Fourier transform a spectrum is a misuse of the term.

Comment: We can define or re-define any variable to mean anything, start using $t$ for frequency and $f$ for time. Im just saying its good sense to use the terminology the field is familiar with instead of redefining it.

Comment: @Mohammad The term spectrum is usually associated with an energy or intensity.  Calling a Fourier transform a spectrum is just wrong.

Comment: Yes, and $S(f)$ is usually associated with the output of a DFT.

Comment: @Mohammad I see the confusion now.  I changed my post so there shouldn't be any issues with symbols.